# Problems with onMessage

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am learning firebase and hit a problem: I can't send notifications. I have tried to use `onMessage`, but it nothing happens at all.

```
var message = {
    content_available: false,

    notification: {
        title: "My first Push",
        body: "My first Push",
    },
    to: token
};
global.admin.messaging().onMessage(function(message) {

        const notificationTitle = message.notification.title;
        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            console.log("This browser does not support system   notifications");
        } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            var notification = new Notification(notificationTitle, message.notification);
            notification.onclick = function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab
                window.open(event.notification.click_action, '_blank');
                notification.close();
            }
        }
        console.log('Message received. ', message);
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Sucsessfully sent message:", response);
        console.log(response.results[0].error);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    })
```

Comment: `onMessage` is a function of the client SDK, not Admin. I'm not sure where your code is coming from, but [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices) is the guide for sending to devices from the Admin SDK

Comment: i see, but before i used "sendToDevice". and i found one point: push dosent work, wen page is opend in chrome-brauser. in firefox all are working

Comment: Reason in firebase-admin, thus common firebase is working